# Is there a way to use commands like \equiv without declaring a function?

Tags: math-operators

I just want to add \equiv to my  sentence but I keep getting an error when trying to compile in texmaker.  Seems like what I need to do is wrap it in \begin{equation} but I don't want to treat it as such.

Comment: You need to be in maths mode e.g. `$\equiv$` or `\[\equiv\]` for inline or display mode respectively. `equation` puts you in maths mode, but it isn't the only way.

Comment: Tried the first one and it worked.  Thanks!  Sorry I'm very new to LaTex and just found mentions of using the equation function.

Comment: You should take the time to read a short introduction so you understand the basics. Otherwise, the whole thing will seem mysteriously and deeply frustrating. I like Kopka & Daly's book but there are others, as well as online resources. Take your pick but read *something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: ways]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
There are many ways to enter maths mode.
  \begin{equation}
    \text{equation} = \text{one way}
  \end{equation}
but
\[
  \text{equation} \not\equiv \text{maths mode}
\]
If $\{x_1,...,x_n\} = \{\text{ways}\}$ then $n \equiv \text{many}$.
\end{document}
```